# How can i fix this, it's not returning text?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm **scraping** https://cadres.apec.fr/home/mes-offres/recherche-des-offres-demploi/liste-des-offres-demploi.html?motsCles=commercial&sortsType=SCORE&sortsDirection=DESCENDING&lieux=590711
this site, i'm having problem with extracting text.

I've tried various ways to but in vain

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hi"
    start_urls = [
        'https://cadres.apec.fr/home/mes-offres/recherche-des-offres-demploi/liste-des-offres-demploi.html?motsCles=commercial&sortsType=SCORE&sortsDirection=DESCENDING&lieux=590711'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.css('span.offre.intitule::text').extract()
        list = {"Name":name}
        yield list
```

Can anyone look into and and help me?

Comment: Check the contents of `response`. Does it have the desired data, but your CSS expression does not capture it? Is it missing the required data? Also, maybe you should configure your Splash request to give Splash more time to render each page, if you are sometimes getting the page without the desired data. Also, know that Splash should be a last resort, see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your css selector is wrong as you are using `offre.intitule` is the value of the `bo-text` attribute. So maybe something like:

```
response.css('[bo-text="offre.intitule"]::text').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've one other problem